# webview.goBack() is works only one time in android WebView

Tags: android, android-webview, android-websettings

hi developers i am working in a webview in android. i loaded a webpage in WebView. then i click some link that contains in the webpage. Then i click the goback button in my application the onclick of the button contains the below code

```
webview.canGoBack();
 backbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                      webview.goBack();
                    }
                 });
```

but this code works only once. it goes only one clicked link back. i want to goback the every clicked url one by one

Comment: Can you be more clear?

Comment: sir please tell me what didn't understand? from this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try it.

```
backbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: can you vote up this question please. because i cant ask other question

Comment: Thank you for your answer nilesh its works well. Thank you again

Comment: @nileshpatel You provide some good answers, but please learn how to use code blocks properly: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. Two hints: 1. Any line that's indented at least 4 spaces will be in a code block, so if you don't add 4 spaces to the whole thing, the lines at the leftmost level will be left out. 2. You don't need to add 4 space to each line manually. Just select the code and click the **{}** in the tool bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can initiate another loading if you override `onPageFinished` method of `WebViewClient` or if you modify `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`.